# How to "real time" echo from controller to view

Tags: yii2

I have a controller which performs some extensive and time consuming operations and I'd like to show its partial results to user; I figure I'd have to deal with "progress bars", have looked at some examples and plugins, but they are far beyond my knowledge (at the moment!).

For now I'd be satisfied with 'echoing' the partial results to a view, in a simple way.

My controller:

```
..
foreach ($response->messages as $msg) {
  ..
  ..(do something)..
  echo (partial results)."<br>";
}
```

So the question is, view is rendered only at the end of my loop, and partial results are shown at once, after a long wait of a blank screen.

I'd like that my 'echos' would appear "real time" during foreach loop. Is that a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a [`flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) with [`ob_flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php).

```
foreach ($response->messages as $msg) {
    // ..(do something)..
    echo (partial results) . "<br>";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
exit;
```

Note that you should call `exit` at the end of method - since 2.0.14 Yii does not allow echo i controller, so you need to manually stop further response processing.